# Call function with parameters from Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Apologies if this has already been asked. I've done some searching and not found a simple solution.

I have a symfony/doctrine project. What is the appropriate  way to call a function from twig given that the business logic should not be placed in the view.

I have an array of objects and I would like to check if the logged in user is the owner of each object in the post.

For example is this appropriate

```
    //in twig template
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% if  post.isOwner(user_id) %}
            //do stuff
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

and in the post entity have this

```
    //in entity    
    public function isOwner(user_id){
        if (post.getId() == user_id)
            return true;
        return false
    }
```

If this isn't best practice, how can this be achieved appropriately.

Comment: Putting logic into entities (that fit the entity) is very good practice in my opinion. If you still have some logic that doesn't fit your entity, and you have to d o that in Twig, you should create Twig extension. But it's a good solution only if this logic belongs to view layer http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont know what u're attempting to do, but if you want to loop through a specific user posts, you'd rather build a bi-directionnal relations and loop on posts using

```
{% for post in app.user.posts %}
```

In the other hand, if you want to loop through all the posts and do some custom logic for posts owned by authed user, you're good to go with your original code. I would change some things though :

For semantic/readability reasons, I would change

```
//in twig template
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if  post.isOwner(user_id) %}
        //do stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
//in twig template
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if  app.user.isOwner(post) %}
        //do stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if  post.isOwnedBy(app.user) %}
        //do stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And I would correct the logic method :

```
//in entity AcmeBundle\User    
public function isOwner(AcmeBundle\Post $post){
    if ($this == $post->getUser()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... this is what I was trying to do. Thanks for the correction as well

Comment: are you looping through a specific user's posts, or looping through a whole collection of posts and doing some custom logic for authed user ?

Comment: I'm looping through a collection of posts. Posts are passed from the controller. Your answer is exactly what I was looking to do.  I wasn't sure if it was best practice to pass a parameter from twig to the the entity

Answer (score 2):

Seems good practice yes. As the logic only spreads over one line, I'd say this is the way to go.
Only remarque is that you can rewrite this code to :

```
{% for post in posts if post.isOwner(user_id)%}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

---

EDIT

This feature was removed in `twig 2.1.0`, either place the if inside the body or use the filter `filter` if you are using a newer version

[documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition)